# How can I combine datatool and tikz for creating a mindmap?

Tags: tikz-pgf, datatool

I’d like to bild a mindmap using a csv and with items based on the column `branch`.

LaTeX is throwing this error message at me:

> ! Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a
> semicolon?.
>
> See the tikz package documentation for explanation. Type  H 
> for immediate help.  ...
> l.63     };

But I could pin it down to the use of the `datatool` syntax in `DTLforeach`.

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees}
\usepackage{xstring}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{partnerships.csv}
branch,name
nhr,name1
nrw,name2
nrw,name3
nrw,name4
nrw,name5
tech,name6
tech,name7
tech,name8
tech,name9
coop,name10
coop,name11
coop,name12
coop,name13
network,name15
network,name16
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLloaddb{partnerships}{partnerships.csv}
\DTLsort{branch,name}{partnerships}

\NewDocumentCommand{\getBranch}{m}{%
  \IfEqCase{#1}{
    {nhr}{Nationales Hochleistungsrechnen}
    {nrw}{Landesdienste NRW}
    {tech}{Tech\-nologie\-partner}
    {coop}{Kooperationen}
    {network}{Netzwerke}
  }}

\tikzset{concept/.append style={fill={none}}}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}


\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=-90]
  \path[mindmap,concept color=black,text=black, grow cyclic]
  node[concept] {RPDM}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  child[concept color=green!50!black] {
      node[concept] {\getBranch{tech}}
    \DTLforeach[\DTLisinlist{\branch}{tech}]{partnerships}{%
    \branch=branch,%
    \name=name%
  }{
    child { node[concept] {\name} }
  }
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    child[concept color=blue!50!black] {
      node[concept] {\getBranch{nrw}}
    \DTLforeach[\DTLisinlist{\branch}{nrw}]{partnerships}{%
    \branch=branch,%
    \name=name%
  }{
    child { node[concept] {\name} }
  }
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### [image]

Additional request: Is there a way also to get the second level of the database, so that the code will create nodes for all the branches and then for the individual items? So I would not need to manually create an entry for the branch, e.g. "tech".